# Factory Reset MacBook Air makes it better?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2011) I did never factory reset it. 
It's getting sometimes slow and have too much heat, I've changed the fan but still got some heat and slow function till I force quit all apps.

Do you think factory reset can make it better? I'm aware to do that cause I have a lot of files to be removed and some are critical to being moved of its location.

Comment: Which OS are you running? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: OS: High Sierra 10.13.2
RAM: 4GB
Processor: 1.7 GHz Intel Core i5

Comment: macOS High Sierra is demanding. Although Apple says, the requirement is 2 GB RAM, it needs at least 8 GB to run smoothly. You have 4 GB RAM with Core i5 processor. I guess you have a HDD, not SSD. The HS would be slow. The fans would run most of the time as they need to cool the laptop. I have a 2011 15" MBP with SSD and HS runs hot with fans running all the time. SO, I went back to El Capitan and no issues. Everything is running fine. I think the MBA is unable to handle the HS.

Comment: It's SSD , but I'll try back to El Capitan , Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall macOS without resetting

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904